# Clarification on Java Language Specification

Tags: java, compile-time, jls

I read the following phrase in the Java language specification.

> It is a compile-time error for the character following the SingleCharacter or
>   EscapeSequence to be other than a '.'

I am not able to understand what is the meaning of above line. Could someone please explain it with example.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4-300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is says is basically: A compile time error will be generated for every character different than a `'`, that comes after the "character" itself. Where the "character" is the content in the form of a character (like: `a`, `0`, `\u0093`) or an escape sequence (like: `\\`, `\b`, `\n`).

So, this will be wrong:

- `'aa'`, because the second `a` is not a single quote (`'`).
- `'\\a'`, because the second character (the `a`) is not a single quote.
- `'a`, because the character which comes after the "content" is not a quote (but probably a newline or a space).

**Side note:** This won't work either: `char c = '\u0027';`. Because that is the code point for a single quote, so it gets translated into: `char c = ''';`.

Comment: Best explanation so far.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is about character literals. Another way to say this is: character literals must be enclosed by apostrophes, it is an error if you forget the second apostrophe.

Hence:

```
'a'          // correct
'\007'       // correct
'ab          // wrong
```

Comment: `'\'` is also wrong. He never said it is a complete list though.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can define character variable as an escape sequences or single characters. Those should be surrounded by single quotes.

```
char ch = 'a'; 
// Unicode for uppercase Greek omega character
char uniChar = '\u039A';
```

More information and examples can be found in Java tutorial on [Characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).